# Solving equalities with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I was goofing around with programming some math functions the other day, and I came up with an equality that I can't prove/disprove.  It involves absolute values and that is where I am getting stumped.

$$ \lvert(x-y)\rvert(x+y) = \lvert x^2 - y^2 \rvert $$

Is it possible to work this out with algebra or otherwise?

Comment: If $x + y < 0$ this equality is not true. Are you trying to prove this equality for positive $x, y$, or are you trying to find conditions such that your equation hold?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prove it for positive values of x,y only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $|x-y| \cdot (x+y) = |x^2-y^2|.$ But
$$x^2 - y^2 = (x-y) \cdot (x+y),$$
so
$$|x-y| \cdot (x+y) = |x-y| \cdot |x+y|.$$

Therefore either $|x-y| = 0,$ or we can divide by it to find that $|x+y| = x+y.$

Hence the two solutions to this inequality are $x=y,$ or $x+y \geq 0.$